# QtXml/qdom.h proplems in a qt project

Tags: qt, qt-creator, fedora, fedora-27

I'm using CGAL , libQGLViewer libraries in a project on QT creator , Fedora 27

but it shows errors on the header file of the libraries

**Compile output:**

```
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:99:20: error: variable ‘Q_XML_EXPORT QDomImplementation’ has initializer but incomplete type
 class Q_XML_EXPORT QDomImplementation
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:101:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘public’
 public:
 ^~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:101:1: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘public’
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:101:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘public’
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:103:30: error: ‘QDomImplementation’ does not name a type
     QDomImplementation(const QDomImplementation&);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:103:50: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token
     QDomImplementation(const QDomImplementation&);
                                                  ^
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:104:26: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token
     ~QDomImplementation();
                          ^
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:105:5: error: ‘QDomImplementation’ does not name a type
     QDomImplementation& operator= (const QDomImplementation&);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:106:28: error: ‘QDomImplementation’ does not name a type
     bool operator== (const QDomImplementation&) const;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:106:49: error: non-member function ‘bool operator==(const int&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
     bool operator== (const QDomImplementation&) const;
                                                 ^~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:106:49: error: ‘bool operator==(const int&)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:107:28: error: ‘QDomImplementation’ does not name a type
     bool operator!= (const QDomImplementation&) const;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:107:49: error: non-member function ‘bool operator!=(const int&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
     bool operator!= (const QDomImplementation&) const;
                                                 ^~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:107:49: error: ‘bool operator!=(const int&)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:110:69: error: non-member function ‘bool hasFeature(const QString&, const QString&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
     bool hasFeature(const QString& feature, const QString& version) const;
                                                                     ^~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:121:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘private’
 private:
 ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:123:51: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token
     QDomImplementation(QDomImplementationPrivate*);
                                                   ^
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:125:5: error: ‘friend’ used outside of class
     friend class QDomDocument;
     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/QtXml/qdom.h:126:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 };
```

all errors appear in QtXml/qdom.h file , I have no idea how to solve them 
I appreciate any help,
thanks

Comment: You better provide a [mcve] to get better help

Comment: What versions of Qt and QGLViewer are you using ?

Comment: @mgimeno QGLViewer library version 2.6.3.

Comment: It should work with QGLViewer 2.6, we used it for a while in the demos. You need at least Qt 5.4 though. You can find example setups in the demos of CGAL, let's say in the package AABB_Tree. Carefully look at the CMakeLists.txt in there, I'd say you are missing . 

Anyway, those errors look like they are generated by a missing `}` in a previously included file, it may be worth checking.